# Pandas: Group By Elements of a Column

Tags: python, pandas

Looking for assistance to `group by` elements of a column in a Pandas df.

Original df:

```
    Country    Feature    Number
0     US         A          1
1     DE         A          2
2     FR         A          3
3     US         B          0
4     DE         B          5 
5     FR         B          7
6     US         C          9
7     DE         C          0
8     FR         C          1
```

Desired df:

```
    Country    A    B    C
0   US         1    0    9
1   DE         2    5    0
2   FR         3    7    1
```

Not sure if `group by` is the best choice if I should create a dictionary. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) for that:

```
In [39]: df.pivot_table(index='Country', columns='Feature')
Out[39]:
        Number
Feature      A  B  C
Country
DE           2  5  0
FR           3  7  1
US           1  0  9
```

If you want your index to be 0, 1, 2 you could use `reset_index`

**EDIT**

If your `Number` actually not numbers but strings you could convert that column with `astype` or with `pd.to_numeric`:

```
df.Number = df.Number.astype(float)
```

or:

```
df.Number = pd.to_numeric(df.Number)
```

*Note*: `pd.to_numeric` is available only for pandas `>= 0.17.0`

Comment: Thanks for answering, @Anton Protopopov! However, this caused the following error: `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`

Any thoughts on how to fix?

Comment: @Levine you should first convert your number from `str` to `int` or `float`

Comment: Thanks, @Anton Protopopv. Now experiencing the error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: ..`

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure that your column contain only numbers?

Comment: @Levine You could convert to number and produce `NaN`s for not number string with `pd.to_numeric(df.Number, errors='coerce')`

Comment: Thanks, @Anton Protopopov!